# Return File from MVC controller using http get

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I am calling the MVC controller which returns a FileResult back using  XMLHttpRequest.
For some reason i don't get a prompt for download/save the file , i do get the file content as the response from the get request(Checked in network tab).

I don't have the url of the file only have contentbytes, so can't use window.location

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use XMLHttpRequest to open file link, do

- Javascript redirect

  window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";
- open popup with that link

Comment: I don't have the url, i only havecontent bytes

Comment: Without url, you can not call XMLHttpRequest. Put screenshot of your network tab

Answer (score 0):

Before returning the file in your controller action, try to add a content-disposition header (directly as below, or using `System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition`).

```
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName);
```

Also have a look at [RFC 6266](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266)

On the client side, call the url that returns the attachment:

```
window.open('..../controller-name/action-that-returns-the-file');
```